# Erro nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

Tags: c#, .net, commit

Então, tô iniciando no git e estou encontrando dificuldades pra commitar um arquivo.

Fiz todo o passo a passo, criei um repositório e consigo chegar até na parte de adicionar (`git add *`), mas na hora de fazer o *commit* aparece o erro:

```
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Mas se eu escrevo `git status` ele retorna a informação abaixo, e
não sei o que fazer para conseguir o *commit*. Podem me ajudar?

```
No commits yet 

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente com `git add .` ao invés de `git add *`